# OneWay DependencyProperty to ViewModel property binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a `UserControl` with a dependency property, I need this property to be bound to a CLR property in the parent ViewModel. I've cooked up a small application to demonstrate the problem.

**UserControl**

```
<UserControl 
         ...
         x:Name="usr">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeProperty, ElementName=usr}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the code behind:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public string SomeProperty
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SomePropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SomePropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomePropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SomeProperty", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Parent View**

```
<Window ... >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Controls:UserControl1 SomeProperty="{Binding SomeText, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Parent ViewModel**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string _SomeText;

    public string SomeText
    {
        get { return _SomeText; }
        set 
        { 
            _SomeText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, what I need is whatever has been entered in the UserControl's `TextBox` (The `SomeProperty` property) will need to update the ViewModel's `SomeText` property.

I do not require two way binding.

*Apologies for the sea of code, but it's all there if anyone wants it.*

Comment: You need mode=OneWayToSource

Comment: @VictorMukherjee Well. I learnt something today. Bonus points if you can get the bound property to update when the text is changed. I've just tried `NotifyOnSourceUpdated` but that didn't seem to work. Currently it'll only update when the TextBox loses focus.

Comment: You have `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged ` in your binding. That is the correct way to have the VM bound property get updated immediately when the text is changed. Are you sure the setter of that property is not getting executed when you type in the text box?

Comment: @Michael Yes, I'm fairly certain that `UpdateSourceTrigger`, in this scenario is listening for the `SomeText` property to change, as opposed to the dependency property, `SomeProperty`.

Comment: Why mess with the Mode?  Just because you don't "require" two way binding doesn't mean you *have* to turn it off.  Just leave it alone.

Comment: You need the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in your `<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeProperty, ElementName=usr}" />` otherwise SomeProperty will not update immediately and so SomeText too.